# Model skyworks si3404 DC DC converter in spice from basic diagram (can it be modeled)

Tags: dc-dc-converter, ltspice, buck, spice

I have a DC DC converter that I'd like to model, I am not a super expert in DC DC converter design (never took the class). The manufacturer provides little to none information on using the chip in a nonisolated buck configuration. (The si3404 Could a reasonable spice model be made from the block diagram? or are there too many variables missing?

I know one thing I am unclear on is the slope compensation, which I would imagine would be a sawtooth running at the switching frequency?

Another thing that I don't really understand would be the "Blanking Time"  (just a delay?)

The rest seems fairly straightforward, I don't need the short circuit detection. The inputs to FBH and FBL are feed into amplifiers with a 100us or 50us delay.

[image]
Source: https://www.skyworksinc.com/-/media/SkyWorks/SL/documents/public/data-sheets/si3404-datasheet.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a fairly common DC-DC IC so, rather than reinventing the wheel, you could use one of the already made models and build upon that. For example [this](https://groups.io/g/LTspice/files/z_groups.io/Files%20sorted%20by%20message%20number/msg_126128/UC3845.zip) is a slightly more readable version of [this](https://groups.io/g/LTspice/files/z_yahoo/Files%20sorted%20by%20message%20number/msg%202385/msg%202385.zip). For the sawtooth you don't need to make it with current generator and resetting switch, unless you intend to replicate the behaviour of the oscillator, itself. So, a simple voltage source will do. If the signal is sawtooth then a `PULSE()` will do, and if it's a RC exponential, use `EXP()`. The soft start can be a simple A-device buffer with an appropriate `tau` value, the `gm` is just a VCCS, the comparator an D-device `schmitt`, while the summer is a simple node where all join.  And the transistors can be VCSW (with or without antiparallel diodes), for speed.